# After updating new version on play store , it still shows installed app

Tags: android, google-play

I deployed new version of my android application on google-play-store. As i assume after publishing , it should notify me to update my application. But i didn't receive any kind of notification even after 2 days. When i un-installed my application and reinstall i got latest version of my application.

- Here question is how can i get notification to update my application
  ?
- Is there any time frame after which on play store installed button
  changed into update button?

Comment: app updates is staged and usually takes time to roll out to all users. If you open the URL in browser from desktop does it show latest version? Try clearing cache or google play store on phone. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Comment: if a user has turned on automatic updates for your app, the update will be downloaded and installed automatically.